# How to disabled logging stdout for apache commons daemon (Procrun)?

Tags: java, apache-commons, procrun

I'm using apache commons daemon tool `Procrun` to install a java command line tool as a windows service.

The java tool displays lots of content on the console during running. Any sysout will automatically be logged by the daemon tool into a logfile. This file cannot be removed as long as the service is running.

Problem: my service and my application should hardly ever be restarted. This results in a daemon `StdOutput` logfile of several hundred GB per month, which I can only clear manually by stopping the app first.

Question: is it possible to disable this service logging?

Comment: Have you tried setting a higher logging level in the configuration file?

Comment: Ok that might be a first workaround. Anyhow it does not disable the stdout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid having your stdout and stderr written to a file by omitting a filename from the configuration script for the `--StdOutput` and `--StdError` parameters. I have this working with v1.0.15.0

For instance:

```
D:\prunsrv.exe //IS//SomeService ^
--DisplayName="SomeService" ^
--Description="Some Procrun Service" ^
--Startup=auto ^
--Install=%CD%\prunsrv.exe ^
--Jvm=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll ^
--Classpath=%CD%\MyApplication-SNAPSHOT.jar; ^
--StartMode=jvm ^
--StartClass=com.myDomain.bootstrap ^
--StartMethod=start ^
--StartParams=start ^
--StopMode=jvm ^
--StopClass=com.myDomain.bootstrap ^
--StopMethod=stop ^
--StopParams=stop ^
--StdOutput= ^
--StdError= ^
--LogPath=%CD%\logs ^
--LogLevel=Debug ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Best Practise for me is a batch-file, which does all for me very simple:

**installService.bat**

```
REM Main
set SERVICE_NAME=MyService
set PR_DESCRIPTION=My Description
set PR_INSTALL=C:\procrun-sample-master\prunsrv.exe
set PR_STARTUP=auto

REM Java
set PR_JVM=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll
set PR_CLASSPATH=myservice.jar

REM LOG disabled
set PR_LOGPATH=C:\procrun-sample-master\log
set PR_STDOUTPUT=
set PR_STDERROR=
set PR_LOGLEVEL=Warn

REM Start Config
set PR_STARTUP=auto
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=package.Classname
set PR_STARTMETHOD=start

REM Stop Config
set PR_STOPMODE=jvm
set PR_STOPCLASS=package.Classname
set PR_STOPMETHOD=stop

REM Install
prunsrv.exe //IS//%SERVICE_NAME%
```

Answer (score 0):

**Got this issue resolved by following below steps.**

1. Stop your apache service via *Services*
2. Open Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator
3. Navigate to your tomcat exe file location ie

   `cd D:\MyApplication\Apache-Tomcat\bin\`
4. Run below command

   `tomcat7.exe //US//JasperGenDoc --StdOutput=`
5. Start your apache service via *Services*